# Creating an Alpine package

Tags: packaging, alpine-linux

I'm trying to create an apk package. I followed the [Alpine Linux - Creating an Alpine package HOWTO](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package).

I think everything is set up as needed. When I try to build package, I get an error:

```
abuild -r
mypackage: Building jaur/mypackage 3.10.5-r0 (using abuild 3.6.0-r2) started Sat, 17 Oct 2020 15:00:13 +0300
mypackage: Checking sanity of /home/jaur/test/APKBUILD...
mypackage: Analyzing dependencies...
ERROR: mypackage: builddeps failed
libdigidoc: Uninstalling dependencies...
ERROR: No such package: .makedepends-mypackage
```

In APKBUILD i have on "makedepends" line:

```
makedepends="git openssl-dev libxml2-dev doxygen 
cmake make gcc bash xxd swig minizip-dev boost-dev 
openjdk10-jdk openldap-dev qt5-qttools-dev 
qt5-qtsvg-dev pcsc-lite-dev xerces-c-dev zip"
```

I also tried, for testing, to build the flac package. I'm sure in aports/main/flac APKBUILD is correct. I didn't change anything there, but I'm getting the same error:

```
>>> flac: Building main/flac 1.3.3-r0 (using abuild 3.6.0-r2) started Sat, 17 Oct 2020 14:59:14 +0300
>>> flac: Checking sanity of /home/jaur/aports/main/flac/APKBUILD...
>>> flac: Analyzing dependencies...
>>> ERROR: flac: builddeps failed
>>> flac: Uninstalling dependencies...
ERROR: No such package: .makedepends-flac
```

Am I doing something wrong, missing some step(s) or something?

Answer (score 2):

My main problem was that I had one broken package in my system. I removed it and everything works.
Also, it would help running `apk fix`.
Word of advice: use clean environment, so that you don't have old .so lying around in the filesystem.